# Multiple Tasks, Each Update UI on Completion

Tags: c#, wpf, task

So I have a `BackgroundWorker` that runs a bunch of tasks like so;

```
taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Task1));
taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Task2));
...
Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

These are placed in a worker so that I can show a loading icon in XAML. Then `worker.RunWorkerCompleted` will remove the loading icon and free up the UI to the user once all the tasks are completed.

Next I would like to update the loading UI as the tasks complete. I.e. as the first task finishes a label under the loading icon will say "Task 1 complete" and so on.

What would be the best way to complete this? I had the thought that I could change the Tasks to BackgroundWorkers, then use their `RunWorkerCompleted` event to update the UI, but I'm wondering is this the correct/best/sensible approach?

Comment: Why don't you just use a thread?

Comment: There's no need for a BGW at all.  If you're using tasks, just `await` them to do work when they're done, rather than creating a new thread just to do nothing but sit there waiting for *another* thread to finish its work.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno The code described is already using lots of threads.

Comment: I mean that he could use another approach with a thread object and not task ^^

Comment: @MarcoSalerno That just loses you functionality, and gains you nothing.

Comment: Depends what you must do

Comment: @MarcoSalerno What does a `Thread` allow you to do that the TPL doesn't that's relevant to the question at hand?

Comment: Awaiting each task will run them sequentially one-by-one.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno a thread means you have to handle *everything*. This is hard enough with one thread and Invokes all around. It's a lot harder with many threads. Tasks, `async/await` etc were created and *do* simplify things immensely

Comment: @mm8 That depends on when and how you await them.  You can trivially run the operations sequentially or concurrently depending on when you start each operation and when you await them.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood what he was trying to do ^^

Comment: @MarcoSalerno So then what do you think that `Thread` gives  you that the TPL can't do here?  What's the thing that you think the question is asking that would require it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ik but reading his code i felt like he was using tasks without needing more than one separated thread ^^

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Why would the fact that you don't need multiple separate threads (something I don't think is actually the code, the code they've shown is using multiple threads at  the same time) make it appropriate to use `Thread` instead of the TPL?

Comment: @windowskm why do you use StartNew? Why `WaitAll`? You can should use `Task.Run` and `async/await` to update the UI. Besides, the proper way to update the UI in WPF is to use data binding. You shouldn't even care how the UI is updated. Modify your ViewModel, raise the NotifyPropertyChanged event and WPF will update the UI

Comment: @Servy nothing, just style ^^

Comment: @MarcoSalerno What about `Thread` is superior style?  Why didn't you mention right off the bat that it doesn't have any advantages, you just prefer the style (it took a *lot* of work just to get you to finally say that's why you're suggesting it)?

Comment: Basically asking for a thread or a task to run it's the same. Depending on your needs in particular situation task can be a better choice

Comment: The point isn't "task or thread" i was meaning that it looked like he didn't need more than one task ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each single Task may update the UI by means of the UI thread's Dispatcher:

```
taskList.Add(Task.Run(() =>
{
    // do lengthy operation

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // update UI
    });
}));
```

Then await all Tasks by `Task.WhenAll` and make the final UI update:

```
await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());

// update UI
```

There is no need for a BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use the `ContinueWith` method and start the tasks on the calling (UI) thread:

```
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Task1);
t1.ContinueWith(task => 
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        textBlock1.Text = "t1 completed";
    }));
});
taskList.Add(t1);

...
await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

Comment: *Why ?* There's no reason for that when `async/await` are available. Besides, this code deadlocks. `Task.WaitAll` will block the UI thread which means no task will be able to update it. So none will finish

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You are wrong. If there was "no reason" to ever use the ContinueWith method, this method would have been marked as deprecated. Awaiting each task will make them run sequentially one after another. And this code doesn't deadlock when being run on a background thread.

Comment: So, one more thread to handle the blocking code that could have been avoided in the first place. When `await Task.WhenAll()` would have avoided the problem. As for deprecated, well, yes, this style *is* obsolete since 4.5. There's even a class to report progress from multiple threads

Comment: You don't need "one more thread". You could call the ContinueWith method on the UI thread and just use await Task.WhenAll. Why would it deadlock?

Comment: @mm8 `ContinueWith` is a low level tool.  There are rare circumstances where it's helpful, or even necessary, but those situations are rare, and virtually always involve the implementation of other higher level tools (like `await`, for example, which is conceptually a higher level tool that creates continuations for you, but with added functionality, functionality that your code is worse for not having).  .NET in general tends to not actually use the obsolete attribute, even when they make their own stuff obsolete (look at, say, `ArrayList`, which no one should ever use anymore).

Comment: You should write an answer on how to solve this using async/await.